# Convert and parse json string to key value pairs using NewtonSoft

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json.net

Trying to convert a json string to key value pairs using Newtonsoft but no luck so far.

Response from the API:

```
var response = @"{'result':{'0199 - B344EE33':
{
     '6400_00260100':{'1':[{'val':336688}]},
     '6400_00462500':{'1':[{'val':null}]},
     '6800_00832A00':{'1':[{'low':3000,'high':3000,'val':3000}]},
     '6800_008AA200':{'1':[{'low':0,'high':null,'val':0}]}
}}}";
```

Result I want is a new object of key value pairs:

```
{
    "6400_00260100" : 336688,
    "6400_00462500" : null,
    "6800_00832A00" : 3000,
    "6800_008AA200" : 0
}
```

In the response the `result` will always be the first and only prop. In the next level the code `0199 - B344EE33` can change but there will be only one prop in this level so we can always take the first one. Then in the last level we always need the `val` property.

What I have is the following but for getting the key value pairs in a clean way I got stuck:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(response);
var result = json["result"].First;
var path = result.Path;
```

**UPDATE**

```
        var jObjectResult = new JObject();

        var response = @"{'result':{'0199 - B344EE33':
                        {
                            '6800_10821E00':{'1':[{'val':'SMA Sunny Boy'}]},
                            '6800_00A21E00':{'1':[{'val':'3.0.0.2222'}]},
                            '6800_00823400':{'1':[{'low':3000,'high':3000,'val':3000}]},
                            '6800_08822B00':{'1':[{'val':'SMA'}]},
                            '6800_08822000':{'1':[{'val':'Sunny Boy 3.0'}]}
                        }}}";

        var json = JObject.Parse(response);
        var json_serial = json["result"].First.Children<JObject>().ToList()[0];

        foreach(var token in json_serial)
        {
            var tokenKey = token.Key;
            var tokenVal = token.Value.SelectToken("$.1[0].val");

            jObjectResult.Add(tokenKey, tokenVal);
        }
```

Comment: Your JSON sample looks like it has several layers of nesting though. You would probably be better off trying to first get that into a c# class object and then projecting the bits you need out into the Dictionary.

Comment: @t.karalis Why would I do that? I only need the key and val values out of it into a dictionary or list or whatever. Creating nested objects to achieve this seems overkill.

Comment: Just coming at it from a different angle, if there was a way to deserialize it without having to parse the json manually, then that would seem way simpler to me ;) Admittedly, I havent come up with something yet.

Comment: Got something working, see update in my question but maybe it can be simplyfied.

Comment: Great, only thing I would avoid is calling `.ToList()` unnecessarily. I'd replace .ToList()[0] with `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SelectTokens` with the recursive descent operator `..` to find all the `val` properties, then walk up the chain using `.Parent` repeatedly to get the corresponding key.  Create new `JProperties` from this information and put them into a new `JObject` to get your result.  Here is a "one-liner":

```
var result = new JObject(
    JObject.Parse(response)
           .SelectTokens("$..val")
           .Select(jt => new JProperty(
               ((JProperty)jt.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent).Name,
               jt
           ))
);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TbZ7LS

Answer (score 0):

At the end with some pointers form @Brian Rogers I came with the following solution:

```
    // Arrange
    var response = @"{'result':{'0199 - B344EE33':
                    {
                        '6800_10821E00':{'1':[{'val':'SMA Sunny Boy'}]},
                        '6800_00A21E00':{'1':[{'val':'3.0.0.2222'}]},
                        '6800_00823400':{'1':[{'low':3000,'high':3000,'val':3000}]},
                        '6800_08822B00':{'1':[{'val':'SMA'}]},
                        '6800_08822000':{'1':[{'val':'Sunny Boy 3.0'}]}
                    }}}";

    // Act
    var json = JObject.Parse(response);
    var json_serial = (JProperty)json["result"].First();
    var jObjectResult = new JObject(
        json_serial.Value.Select(p =>
        {
            return new JProperty(
                ((JProperty)p).Name,
                p.First.SelectToken("$.1[0].val")
            );
        }));
```